# sum of elements converge in Hilbert space implies convergence of square

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question about a statement which I don't know if it is true. Given a Hilbert space $H$, if we have a sequence of element $\{c_k\}$, with $||\sum_I c_k||\leq A$, where $I$ is any finite index set and $A$ is independent of $I$. Can we say $\sum||c_k||^2<\infty$? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: if $K$ is compact then every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can you explain it in more detail? Thanks！